# Qual a diferença em HotDeploy e Publish, Start e com o se relacionam

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Quando adiciono o tomcat ao eclipse algumas opções me aparecem : `Start` be `Publish`.
Como essas se relacionam com o `hotdeploy`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Start` e `Debug`

A opção `Start` irá inicializar o servidor e, como consequência, as aplicações que estiverem associadas ao mesmo. É o equivalente ao `Run` para JavaSE. Se quiser depurar a aplicação use a ção `Debug`.

## `Publish`

Já a opção `Publish` irá copiar os arquivos alterados no seu projeto para a pasta configurada no seu Tomcat, tornando-os disponíveis para novas requisições. Mas note que isso não implica em reiniciar o servidor, então se o tomcat estiver configurado para fazer cache pode não surtir efeito imediato.

Além disso, por padrão o Tomcat fica configurado para fazer o `Publish` automático quando você altera um arquivo no projeto. Essa configuração pode ser alterada clicando na opção `Properties` do menu apresentado na pergunta.

Às vezes o Eclipse perde a sincronia entre projeto e Tomcat por algum motivo. Você pode então abrir o item do Tomcat clicando na seta, clicar com o botão direito em uma aplicação específica e selecionar a opção `Full Publish`, que irá forçar a cópia completa da aplicação para a pasta do Tomcat.

## *Hot Deploy*

É a capacidade de atualizar o sistema sem reiniciar o Tomcat ou a Aplicação.

Entretanto, há várias situações a se considerar:

- Alteração de configuração: depende do framework reconhecer essas alterações
- Alteração em classes: no JDK normal funciona se estiver em modo Debug e se não alterar assinaturas de métodos ou criar novos atributos em classes.
- Alteração de recursos estáticos: funciona bem para imagens, scripts, etc., mas se tiver algum tipo de framework para as *views* vai ter que configurá-lo para recarregá-las.

Enfim, cada tecnologia tem as suas nuances.

Porém, o maior problema de precisar reiniciar a aplicação (se ela não for muito lenta), é que a sessão será perdida e você precisará logar novamente e reiniciar os testes. Por isso é interessante implementar um login que redirecione o usuário para a última página que ele estava acessando.